# What are the P(0) and P(1) probabilities for the T transformation in quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

I'm just starting of on quantum computing, specifically following the IBM Q Experience documentation <sup>[1]</sup>. In here, they are explaining the following experiment:

$T|+\rangle$

The expected outcomes according to the document:

- Phase angle: $\pi/4$
- Gates: $T$
- Prob 0: 0.8535533
- Prob 1: 0.1464466
- X-length: 0.7071067

I'm trying to deduce this with math.

$T |+\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/4}\end{bmatrix} {1\over\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = {1\over\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix}1\\e^{i\pi/4}\end{bmatrix}$

I think I now need to split this out in $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ so that I get the quantum amplitudes:

$ = {1\over\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} + {1\over\sqrt 2} e^{i\pi/4} \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Here things are falling apart, as

$ P(0) = |{1\over\sqrt 2}|^2 = 0.5 $ 
$ P(1) = |{1\over\sqrt 2} e^{i\pi/4}|^2 = 0.5 $

So my question: **How do I correctly calculate the probabilities and the X-length?**

[1]: [IBM Q: User Guide / The Weird and Wonderful World of the Qubit / Introducing Qubit Phase](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/proxy/tutorial/full-user-guide/002-The_Weird_and_Wonderful_World_of_the_Qubit/003-Introducing_qubit_phase.html)

Comment: You're Measuring in the wrong basis. you’ve done it in the z basis when you should be using the x basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct with your calculation that
$$
T\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)/\sqrt{2}=\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ e^{i\pi/4} \end{array}\right)/\sqrt{2},
$$
and you are correct that if you want to calculate the probability of getting a "0"$\equiv\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$ measurement result, you evaluate
$$
P(0)=\left|\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ e^{i\pi/4} \end{array}\right)/\sqrt{2}\right|^2=\frac{1}{2},
$$
so you get both answers with probability 1/2. However, this is not what the referenced page is trying to calculate. It says

> If we start with a system initially in the |+⟩ (which is done using the Hadamard), then apply multiples of the T gate and measure in the x-basis...

The X-basis is not the question of 0 or 1 that you have already calculated. Instead, it's the probability of being in $|\pm\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ \pm 1\end{array}\right)$. I think the confusion has arisen because while people often refer to 0 and 1 as being the computational basis (as I have, and you have), when you're talking about measurements where there are two possible results, you can always label the outcomes as 0 and 1, no matter what basis was used. This is what they've done.

So,
$$
P(+)=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ e^{i\pi/4} \end{array}\right)/\sqrt{2}\right|^2=\frac{1}{4}|1+e^{i\pi/4}|^2
$$
Expanding this gives
$$
P(+)=\frac{1}{4}\left((1+\cos\frac{\pi}{4})^2+\sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left((1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}
$$
If you numerically evaluate this, you'll get the required result, 0.8535533. You could repeat the calculation for $P(-)$, or just use the fact that $P(+)+P(-)=1$.

The x-length, as they call it, is
$$
P(+)-P(-)=2P(+)-1=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}-1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
Again, that's exactly what's claimed.

Comment: Your math appears to work out, and thereby answer my question, so thank you for that. Still, I have some concerns/unclear parts. 

According to https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa14/lectures/lecture89.pdf:
$|\phi\rangle = A_0 \times |0 \rangle + A_1 \times |1 \rangle$; 
$P(0)=|A_o|^2$ instead of $P(0)=||0 \rangle \times A_o|^2$; 

Without the $|0 \rangle$, $P(+) = |(\alpha + \beta)/sqrt(2))|^2$ (as discussed in the link) works out. 

My remaining question: how could you add $(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, aka $|0 \rangle$ into the $P(0)=|A_0|^2$?

Comment: This seems a bit jumbled/muddled. Can I suggest expanding into a separate question, then i’ve got a better chance of understanding what you're asking, and giving a decent answer?

Comment: You use $P(0)=|A_o \times |0 \rangle |^2$. Should it not be $P(0)=|A_o |^2$ based on https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa14/lectures/lecture89.pdf

Comment: I believe you turned the use of $|+\rangle$ and $T|+\rangle$ around, taking the complex conjugate transpose of $|+\rangle$ instead of $T|+\rangle$, which eventually did not change the outcome thanks to taking the absolute value?

Comment: I believe I've done it correctly for the question as specified. The state produced was $T|+\rangle$, so the probability of being found in the + state is $|\langle +|T|+\rangle|^2$, which is exactly what I've calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were (almost?*) correct, and pointed me in the right direction for computing any probability for a measurement(especially the notion that I was measuring in the wrong basis), but I missed the definition.

Assuming you are in state $|\psi\rangle$, and you want to know the probability of measuring outcome $|\phi\rangle$:
$P=|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2$ (https://ocw.tudelft.nl/course-lectures/0-3-1-measuring-qubits-standard-basis/ @1:48)
where $\langle\psi|$ is the complex conjugate transpose of the $|\psi\rangle$

More, concrete, if we are in $T |+\rangle$ ($\equiv{1\over\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix}1\\e^{i\pi/4}\end{bmatrix}$), and want to know the probability of measuring $|+\rangle$ ($\equiv{1\over\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})$, we calculate:
$P=|{1\over\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix}1 & e^{-i\pi/4}\end{bmatrix}{1\over\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}|^2$
$P={1\over4}|1+e^{-i\pi/4}|^2 \approx 0.853553$ (or use Euler's formula for the exact outcome)

P.S. I hope I took the right complex conjugate. 
* I also have the $\psi$ and $\phi$ the other way around compared to DaftWullie his/her answer.

Comment: I would recommend putting this in a separate question, or editing your main question with this additional piece. Since I think people will probably miss that you had a followup and assume that @DaftWullie took care of it!

But you are correct, and the order of $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ doesn't matter since that only changes the conjugation, which doesn't matter when you are taking the norm.

Comment: Well, this is a matter of practicality. I do the calculation by saying "I have state $|\psi\rangle$, so the amplitude for being in state $|\phi\rangle$ is $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$, and hence the probability is $|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2$ but you don't have to think about it like that. The point is simply that $|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2=\langle\phi|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\phi\rangle=\langle\psi|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$, so once you take the mod-square, ordering is irrelevant. You're taking a marginally less conventional ordering from that lecture, but it makes no difference.